# How to convert ethanal to 2-hydroxy-3 butenoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

How to convert ethanal to 2-hydroxy-3 butenoic acid?

I tried crossed aldol condensation with formaldehyde followed by acid addition.After that how should I proceed ?

Comment: Note that 2-hydroxybut-3-enoic acid has four carbon atoms and ethanal has two. What is the product of the aldol self-condensation of ethanal? Does that give you any hints?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Once you have got your acrolein from the aldol condensation of ethanal and formaldehyde you can react it with $\ce{NaCN, HCN}$ under kinetic control to get direct addition of the cyanide to the enone, forming a cyanohydrin[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kQgu2j_ber0C&pg=PA504&lpg=PA504&dq=direct+addition+of+cyanide+to+enone&source=bl&ots=AoR2Q3Hckh&sig=EZG3Eftl_bs7G1e-777Wmm7VegQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja6ZmhjfXMAhVqAsAKHUOyDNgQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=direct%20addition%20of%20cyanide%20to%20enone&f=false). The nitrile can then be hydrolysed in aqueous acid to yield the carboxylic acid.